# Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0 i followed this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ but getting error Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0 in tutorial mavenCentral() is present in repositories of build script but in Android studio it is jcenter() i have tried changing repositories also followed stackoverflow Q&A regarding this question but none of them helped me please suggest me solution

Comment: Can you show the code in your Build.gradle file?

Comment: may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798984/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-android-sdk4-4-0/31926935#31926935

Answer (score 0):

Put following code in your global build.gradle

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}
```