# Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

Below is code from my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'
}
```

When I do Sync project with gradle files, it gives me error.

```
  Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Similar question has been asked here but no one has answered it. (
[Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363054/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-android-sdk4-0-0) )

Comment: Works for me.  Do you have an internet connection when you're building?

Comment: did you get the solution? please tell me if solved? :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally after spending 6-8 hours on it. I got the solution for you. You have to just change repositories section in your app `build.gradle` file. change it from `mavenCentral` to `jcenter` as following

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }    
}
```

After having this, You can simply add the dependency as

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This,

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.1'
}
```

### Information

`buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"` is not stable purely .Set  `minSdkVersion 15`

Comment: According to maven.org, 4.4.0 is the latest version available through maven repo. http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfacebook-android-sdk

Comment: I tried with compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.1' too and it didn't work. I also tried build version 22.0.1 and min sdk as 15. It didn't work

Comment: m also stuck in the same problem. dont know what to do