# Can't resolve compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, dependencies

Before posting this question I have tried this solutions:-

[Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798984/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-android-sdk4-4-0)

[Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363054/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-android-sdk4-0-0)

Gradle was successfully building before I have updated my sdk to 24. After updating to 24, it shows this error.
On the other hand it is working fine others android studio.

I am confused what is the problem, is problem is in my android studio or sdk 24.

I have tried in android studio 2.2.2 and 1.3.

Comment: in which studio is it running fine ?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798984/failed-to-resolve-com-facebook-androidfacebook-android-sdk4-4-0

Comment: @LoveAndroid i have 2.2.2